# rails db migration, undefined method `to_sym', can't figure out syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Here is my original migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
        t.string :login, :limit => 40
        t.string :name, :limit => 100, :default => '', :null => true
        t.string :email, :limit => 100
        t.string :crypted_password, :limit => 40
        t.string :salt, :limit => 40
        t.string :remember_token, :limit => 40
        t.datetime :remember_token_expires_at
        t.string :activation_code, :limit => 40
        t.datetime :activated_at, :datetime
        t.string :state, :null => :no, :default => 'passive'
        t.datetime :deleted_at
        t.integer :occupation_id, :null => :yes
        t.datetime :paid_up_to_date, :date
        t.timestamps
      end
```

I am trying to change the default of "state" to be "active" instead of passive
Here is my second attempt;

```
class ChangeUserStateDefault < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :users, :state, :null => :no, :default => 'active'
end
```

Comment: Post the entire error: the part that comes before and after "undefined method".  The question is which class/object is raising that error?

Comment: ==  ChangeUserStateDefault: migrating =========================================
-- change_column(:users, :state, {:default=>"active", :null=>:no})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for {:default=>"active", :null=>:no}:Hash

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The error is because you were missing the type of the column.
[Usage](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column):

> ```
> change_column(table_name, column_name, type, options = {})
> ```

**So this should work for you:**

```
change_column :users, :state, :string, :null => false, :default => 'active'
```